# Failed to connect to localhost port 9200

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, sylius

when i call `curl http://localhost:9200` outside the containers it works fine, however when I call it inside the php container, I have an error: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused`

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            target: sylius_php
            cache_from:
                - quay.io/sylius/php:latest
                - quay.io/sylius/nodejs:latest
                - quay.io/sylius/nginx:latest
        image: quay.io/sylius/php:latest
        container_name: php
        environment:
            USER_ID: 1000
            APP_ENV: ${APP_ENV}
            APP_DEBUG: ${APP_DEBUG}
            APP_SECRET: ${APP_SECRET}
            PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE: ${PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE:-UTC}
        volumes:
            - .:/srv/sylius:rw,cached
            - ./public:/srv/sylius/public:rw,delegated
            - public-media:/srv/sylius/public/media:rw

    elasticsearch:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.4.3
        container_name: elasticsearch
        environment:
            - cluster.name=docker-cluster
            - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
            - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
        ulimits:
            memlock:
                soft: -1
                hard: -1
        volumes:
            - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        ports:
            - 9200:9200
        networks:
            - esnet

    elasticsearch2:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.4.3
        container_name: elasticsearch2
        environment:
            - cluster.name=docker-cluster
            - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
            - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
            - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch"
        ulimits:
            memlock:
                soft: -1
                hard: -1
        volumes:
            - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        networks:
            - esnet

volumes:
    esdata1:
        driver: local
    esdata2:
        driver: local

networks:
    esnet:
```

The problem is that i need to have access to the elasticsearch server from my php container to be able to execute certain commands related to php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every container has a different IP on the internal network, but it's accessible under a host corresponding to it's service name, in your case it will be http://elasticsearch:9200 and http://elasticsearch2:9200.

Comment: It doesn't work `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: elasticsearch`

Comment: Your PHP container is not on the same network.
You have network `esnet` and add both ES containers to it, but not the PHP container.

Comment: how do you solved this??